# cannot connect to my mqtt broker on ubuntu laptop from niether phone nor esp32

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto on my ubuntu laptop and tried connecting using mobile hotspot and wifi router through my phone and esp32.

i have allowed anonymous listener ,port 1883,ufw disabled but cannot connect to it.

i can publish and subscribe using two terminals using -h my ip address

```
mosquitto -c /home/harsh/test.conf -v
```

my .conf file

```
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
allow_anonymous true
```

Logs

```
1696688646: mosquitto version 2.0.18 starting
1696688646: Config loaded from /home/harsh/test.conf.
1696688646: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1696688646: mosquitto version 2.0.18 running
```

I also tried using different config files

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77250225/edit) to show the `test.conf` file and details of how you have configured your esp32. Also it is very possible that both your phone and hotspot are doing something called "client separation" which means that no 2 clients can talk to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the configuration file looks right and if the firewall is disengaged then the most likely problem is that the hotspot and phone both have "client separation" enabled.

If this cannot be disabled in the hotspot settings then you will have to give a different WiFi access point solution.